# how ext4 works with fallocate

Tags: ext4, fallocate

Recently, I am testing the proper usage of ext4 filesystem. what is my expert is that:

when system crashed,  the data had been write return ok  can not loss, but  metadate can.
Here is my usage:
      1. call fallocate to alloc centain space
         fallocate(fd, 0, 0, 4*1024*1024);    //4MB
      2. call fsync(fd)  let data and metadata write to disks
      3. then i call function to randomly write the file with 4k   size(random data but not 0).  with O_DRICT flag，but not call fsync.  I log the offset with return write ok.
      4. check the offset that logged. but i find in some offset, read 4k data, is 0. It seems mean that offset isn't used like hole files.

My question is that:
   <1. why after calling fallocate and fsync the metadata of the file still seems
indicate some blocks is not used, so when read it return null. It is my understand .
   <2. have other api to call, can make sure that in allocate space with file is not holes ,after that  when write data return ok with O_DIRECT  can make sure the data will not be loss even the system crashed.

```
Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Only writing to the file space can eliminate the hole. Without writing, there is no dirty page and fsync simply does nothing.

I am wondering how did you execute you step 4. It seems that you did it by a manual crash, did you? If you read it after write without a crash, it should not be zero, provided you wrote non-zeros. If you read it after a crash,  zero can happen if disk cache existed. However, this kind of zero is not like holes, they are zeros read from the disk (very probably the disk contains zeros).